# Alternative to lstrcmp() for accented character comparison

Tags: sorting, mfc, ascii, extended-ascii

I was working on sorting some list of words which includes some accented characters(Extended ASCII characters). I found this API is not working properly for accented character. I googled this and found it work well only for English characters. It works by converting the characters in Uppercase and then compare the weights.For ref [See here](https://forum.powerbasic.com/forum/user-to-user-discussions/source-code/24941-national-word-sorting-according-to-locale-setting-using-lstrcmp-and-lstrcmpi). Please see the code snippet below :

`int Ret = lstrcmp( L"Deäft", L"Deept" );`

I was expecting the return value as 1 but it is returning -1.
After sorting,

I am getting as

```
Deäft 
Deept
```

but expecting as

```
Deept
Deäft
```

Can spmebody help me to find and alternative to this API or how to make changes to get expected sorting.

Thanks.

Comment: `CompareStringEx`

Comment: CollateNoCase too

Comment: Yes, `CollateNoCase` is probably easier, or `wcsicoll`